# accessing files in meteor

Tags: node.js, meteor

I have a use case to create documents on the fly inside my meteor app. So I have a template document stored in the meteor folder and some static images that I embed in the documents in my app.
The users also take pictures using camera inside and the app and I also upload them to a folder in meteor app, these are also embedded in the document which is created.
Currently I am storing these files in .uploads as a folder inside my app and accessing it. When I do it in my local I have no problem but I am not sure how this is getting copied to the deployed app and how to access these files.

I am using windows for development so process.env.PWD is not working in my local dev.
So I am using the below code to get it working in local but it doesn't work in server.

```
var base = process.cwd();
console.log("base path:", base);
var afterresolvefind = base.split('.meteor')[0];
var path = Meteor.npmRequire('path');
var inputpath = ".uploads//templates//input.docx"
filepath = path.join(afterresolvefind, inputpath);
```

[image]